# How to return the data from mysql database and use this data in other function to create json data for an API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node js.And here I am trying to use data from mysql database into another function to create a json for another request.

```
app.get("/read/singledata/script/:id",(req,res)=>{
getScriptById(req.params.id)// Returns a Promise!
  .then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
     res.send(result)
})
  .catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
  })
 })
```

Here is my getScriptById method-

```
function getScriptById(id){
 var response=  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query(`SELECT*FROM Script WHERE id=${id}`,(err,result) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
     return resolve(result)
    })
  })
 return response;
 }
```

The above method returns a data from database(used promise) and i want to use this returned data into the following api to create its json data. However, the issue is that I am unable to use the data returned from getScriptById outside the scope of promise function. The data outside it's scope is always undefined.

```
app.post("/autopilotapis/lab", (req, res) => {
    **script.getScriptById(1).then(function(result) {
        //use this result into json
    })**
    console.log(a) 
const requestOptions = {
        url: ' https://autopilot.cloudcx.ai/lab_autopilot',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "id": `${randomid}`,
            "to": "+917302624033",
            "from": "+441834822837",
            "customer_id": `${randomid}`,
            "messages": {
                "autopilot": [{
                    "ivr": "Hello",
                    "ai": "welcome to vodafone",
                    "delay": 0,
                    "step": 0
                }, {
                    "ivr": "customer",
                    "ai": "how can i help you",
                    "delay": 0,
                    "step": 0
                }, {
                    "ivr": "i want to know about bill",
                    "ai": "call_terminate",
                    "delay": 0,
                    "step": 0
                }]
            },
            "language": "en-US",
            "sprint_name": "",
            "sprint_id": "141",
            "channel_name": "NLU BOT",
            "test_type": "Automatic Testing",
            "successCriteria": "Confidence",
            "criteriaValue": "80",
            "step": "false"
        }
    }
    request(requestOptions, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.send(body);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(response);
        }
    });
})
```

I need to use the data from the highlighted part ie getScriptById to create Json(currently hard coded).How can I do it? I have lot of things but I don't understand how to proceed here. Any idea or alternatives?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to wait for the promise to return (i.e. write your subsequent logic inside `then`). Otherwise the data won't be defined. You could also use the simplified syntax with async/await so that it does not look like it is nested into a separate function.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I understand what you just explained. However, what if i have multiple, say 2 more methods like getScriptById(all returning promises) which return some data from database that I need to use to form this json. In that case, in which **then** I should write the logic? How should I resolve this problem?